# Copy part of memory allocated using cudamallocHost

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I would like to copy part of an array from pinned memory on the host to a CUDA device. For example, I've allocated pinned memory of size 500, I would like to copy elements 100-399 to an array of size 300 on the device.

This is my code,

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 500;
    const unsigned int bytes = N * sizeof(int);
    cudaError_t status = cudaSuccess;

    int *h_a;
    int *d_a;

    status = cudaMallocHost((void**) &h_a, bytes);
    if (status != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "Error allocating pinned host memory\n";

    status = cudaMalloc((void**) &d_a, bytes);
    if (status != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "Error allocating pinned device memory\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        h_a[i] = i;
    }

    status = cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a + 100, bytes - (200 * sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (status != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "Error copying to device: " << cudaGetErrorString(status) << "\n";
    cudaMemcpy(h_a + 100, d_a, bytes - (200 * sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (status != cudaSuccess)
        cout << "Error copying to host: " << cudaGetErrorString(status) << "\n";       


    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFreeHost(h_a);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get this error for the host-to-device copying,

```
Error copying to device: invalid argument
```

Only the host-to-device copy fails. The device-to-host copy works fine. Also, the same code works correctly if I use non-pinned host memory. Is there any way to achieve this using pinned memory?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted and it runs for me without any runtime errors.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. Sorry for wasting your time. Possibly, I was running a different executable which was using old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code actually compiles and runs properly. Perhaps I was using an old executable while I was testing it.

Comment: Please remember to come back in a few days and accept your answer so this question falls off the unanswered question list.